# Ansible: execute tasks.yml from playbook.yml

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I searched a lot for exact the same thing that I wanted to do, but found nothing. So, I'm here to ask:

I have a playbook.yml, where defined some tasks. The first task of that playbook is checking existence of file and, if file exists I want to execute **only** the tasks, that are defined in the tasks.yml file and stop executing of tasks from playbook.yml (or vice versa). 
I have read Ansible documentation of course, first of all. But I still don't get if I'm able to do exactly what I want with import/include_tasks modules (tried both of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"Checking the existence of a file*"

A: Use [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status). For example

```
- stat:
    path: /etc/foo.conf
  register: st
```

> Q: *"If the file exists execute tasks, that are defined in tasks.yml file"*

A: Use [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#include-tasks-dynamically-include-a-task-list). For example

```
- include_tasks: tasks.yml
  when: st.stat.exists
```

> Q: "*Stop executing of tasks from playbook.yml*"

A: Use [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html#meta-execute-ansible-actions). For example

```
- meta: end_play
  when: st.stat.exists
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I wasn't clear enough with my question: the task, that is "checking existence of a file", is used for existence of docker container, so I use shell module it this way:
name: Check if there is no container on the host
    command: docker ps -a | grep container_name
    register: existence
    ignore_errors: yes

And after that, as you mentioned, I use include_tasks module. But it still works in an unexpected way (I don't understand something, I guess).

And thank you very much for mentioning the meta module, I will add that.

Answer (score 0):

roles/includeandend/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Unconditional include
  include_tasks: include.yml

- name: include only if file exists
  include_tasks: '{{ item }}'
  vars:
    params:
      files:
        - includeandend.yml
  #  query() returns a blank list for the loop if no files are found.
  loop: "{{ q('first_found', params, errors='ignore') }}"

- debug:
    msg: "If included, this will not execute"
```

roles/includeandend/tasks/include.yml

```
---
- debug:
    msg: "In an included file. Play will continue."
```

roles/includeandend/tasks/includeandend.yml

```
---
- debug:
    msg: "In an included file. Play will end now."

- meta: end_play
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  roles:
    - includeandend
```

---

In Ansible, it is typical to assume a tasks file exists within a given project. The playbook author will write it that way.

My implementation works around that by only including if exists with a `first_found` lookup.

Because of the requirement to stop playbook.yml, I use `meta: end_play`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll try to implement your variant on the playbook.